# How do I handle markup inside of a CreativeWork text property

Tags: html, schema.org, json-ld

I want to format a set of articles using schema.org, however the articles are not *just* text. They contain links, `<em>`s, `<strong>`s, and other light-weight markup. How do I put this in the `text` property correctly?

I considered just putting the markup in there, and that makes sense when it's inside of annotated HTML:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
  <h1 itemprop="name">An example I just wrote</h1>
  <p itemprop="text">here's a <a href="http://example.com">link</a>, it's very <em>important</em></p>
</div>
```

But if I were storing this as JSONLD, it would be rather strange to assume that text should be interpreted as HTML:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "name": "An example I just wrote"
  "text": "here's a <a href=\"http://example.com\">link</a>, it's very <em>important</em>"
}
```

It's entirely possible that I could be writing with Markdown:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "name": "An example I just wrote"
  "text": "here's a [link](http://example.com), it's very _important_"
}
```

Or any other language capable of expressing that same idea. And *which* language I'm using is rather important, because it indicates how the text should be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it explicit what language you used, you can [type the value](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#typed-values). Taking your snippet above, it would look somewhat like this using the [rdf:HTML datatype](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-html):

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "name": "An example I just wrote"
  "text": {
    "@value": "here's a <a href=\"http://example.com\">link</a>, it's very <em>important</em>",
    "@type": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#HTML"
  }
}
```